# Why is random number generation from a kernel distribution up to 1000x slower if truncated?

Tags: matlab, random, truncate

I would prefer to truncate my Distribution, but at the moment it is simply not possible given the time penalty.

Standard Kernel Distribution:

```
expectation=fitdist(BTS,'kernel');
```

Result:

```
tic;expectation.random(10000,1);toc;
Elapsed time is 0.000745 seconds.
```

Truncate Code:

```
Exp{i,j}=truncate(expectation,min(BTS)-1,max(BTS)+1);
```

Result:

```
tic;random(Exp{i,j},1,10000);toc
Elapsed time is 0.772295 seconds.
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the same `random` function that is being called?

Comment: Yes, same speed when run as tic;random(expectation,10000,1);toc;

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue on MATLAB R2017b, Mac version. Curious to know the answer to this problem.

Comment: I don't have the stats toolbox, but my guess is that `truncate` makes a more complex distribution object, which takes longer to evaluate. And it seems that `random` evaluates the object for every number generated. You should consider submitting this as a bug to the MathWorks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try, as an alternative, to draw random numbers from the non-truncated distribution and do the truncation yourself.

I don't have the statistics toolbox, so will use `randn` here to draw random numbers:

```
function M = truncated_normal(n)
M = randn(n,1);
I = M < -2 | M > 2;
n = nnz(I);
if n>0
   M(I) = truncated_normal(n);
end
```

This function draws `n` random numbers from the given distribution, then finds any values that are outside of the chosen interval (`M < -2 | M > 2`), and draws new values for those by recursively calling itself.

The function could also be written with a while loop if you prefer. But as long as the probability of a random value being in the tails is small, very few iterations are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is a more of a comment, but it was too long to fit in the comments section.

Matlab does not necessarily provide the fastest means of generating random numbers. One extreme case is the binomial random variable, which matlab generates through drawing `n` Bernoulli numbers and summing them together. Your example is simply another case.

I suggest you either

- implement a sampling yourself, thus you can tweak it for your needs,
- or use the one by Chopin, see the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6140), which you can get [here](http://miv.u-strasbg.fr/mazet/rtnorm/rtnormM.zip), which is (to my knowledge) the newest such algorithms

Please note, that even though "truncating" sounds like it is making things easier/faster this is not necesarrily the case. Especially nowadays where there exist very fast generators for the normal distribution. On the other hand, the x1000 is too large of a penalty, compared to better methods.